# MySQL user creation date, modified date

Tags: mysql, database, mysqladmin

I have a question to all you MySQL experts out there: Is it possible to see when a user was created in MySQL? Let's say I create a user called 'monty':

`CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' [...]`

how can I see when I created this user? Is there also a way to check how the details of this user got modified?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. The only thing you can do is analyzing binary logs of MySQL Server; but internally it does not store neither user creation date nor modification dates/details.

If you're creating a new software or adding a feature to the existing one you might consider creating/modifying users through your stored procedures only, while in the same stored procedures you can log theis parameters, current date and everything else you want to.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Much appreciated. It's a shame, this function would come pretty handy at some point. I do like your advice about the SPROCs! Thank you again.